# Agricola Solo "Campaign" professions

Tags: agricola

In my solo campaign I played the "Home teacher" (The card that shows Obi Wan) and chose that as my first fixed profession for the following rounds. The card says something like:

> At the end of the game you receive one bonus point for every profession you play after this one.

**1** In the second game when I already have the teacher laying on the table and choose profession. Is that profession free or does it cost 1 food?

**2** Also from the third game on I had the Teacher and other professions laying on the table from the start. Do all these professions give bonus points at the end or just the ones I actually play in that round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Yes, you need to pay 1 food for your second occupation.  Note that the action space on the board reads:

> A player's first occupation is free, each additional one costs 1 food

It doesn't say anything like "first occupation played from your hand" or anything like that.

- Yes, you get bonus points for any occupation played after the *Home Teacher*.  Per the solo rules, you choose the occupations as you play them.  There is an implied ordering, just make sure you chose the Home Teacher first!